# FTP/SFTP sending prefixed temp files with Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

SI's FTP and SFTP Outbound Adapters allow sending temp files with a customizable suffix defaulting to `.writing`. But I'm interfacing with a legacy system that only plays well with prefixed named temp file renames (e.g. `S*`-> `F*`).

After a quick spelunk through the source, I can't find a temp file prefix property or a temp file naming strategy intfc to use.

That said, I can likely use the [RemoteFileTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/RemoteFileTemplate.html)'s API to disable temp files, send, and rename any way I want.

What's a better option than RemoteFileTemplate for implementing a prefixed temp file rename scheme?

Comment: Doesn’t `use-temporary-filename = “false” work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a prefix instead of a suffix for the temporary file name is not supported.

You could use the `RemoteFileTemplate` as you suggest; or [contribute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc) an enhancement.

Comment: I wonder if we could introduce something like `TemporaryFileNameStrategy` with the `SuffixTemporaryFileNameStrategy` as one of the implementation out-of-the-box. So, this way you will just need to inject your custom, prefix-based implementation and `RemoteFileTemplate` will do its hard work on the matter.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I **really** like your new strategy intfc idea. Both for your new 5.x line and backported to 4.x.

Comment: Well, let's get +1 from Gary and raise a JIRA on the matter and then we will consider what and how to do! I think it's not worth for backporting since there is a mentioned workaround